# getting the .ts filename from ffprobe for corresponding pts in a live HLS stream

Tags: http-live-streaming, ffprobe

Currently using ffprobe to get a number of metrics from a HLS live stream. However is there a way to get the name of the .ts that is being inspected?

```
ffprobe -v error -show_entries frame=pts,pkt_pts,pkt_pts_time,pkt_dts,pkt_dts_time -select_streams v -of default=noprint_wrappers=1 "https://livedev.host.net/hls/live/001/test_stream/playlist.m3u8"
```

Current output:

```
pts=7121767234

pkt_dts=7121767234

pkt_dts_time=79130.747044

pts=7121770237

pkt_dts=7121770237

pkt_dts_time=79130.780411

pts=7121770237

pkt_dts=7121770237

pkt_dts_time=79130.780411
```

if possible output:

```
20230515T113200/playlist_512/00007/playlist_512_00601.ts

pts=7121770237
    
pkt_dts=7121770237
    
pkt_dts_time=79130.780411
```